# pyuic5 with python3.6 error

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyuic

I'm trying to use the pyuic5 command in the terminal to convert a QT designer .ui file to a .py file. Here is the command:

```
pyuic5 cone.ui -o cone.py
```

The error I get is:

```
/usr/local/bin/pyuic5: line 2: exec: python3.6: not found
```

Here is the contents of the pyuic5 file:

```
#!/bin/sh 
exec python3.6 -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic ${1+"$@"}
```

Anyone else getting this error?

Comment: try changing python3.6 to python3 or only  python

Comment: `which python3.6`

Comment: Changing to python3 worked. Thank you!